# Limpiar input type text cuando le de click al boton

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Hola necesito que cuando le de click para mandar el dato se borre lo que escribo pero sin usar un boton reset este es mi codigo de mi boton

ESTE ES MI HTML Y JAVASCRIPT

```
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Digite cédula de Tecnicos Disponibles:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_tec_ins"></input>
  <input id="txt_tec_ins_id_tecnicos" type="hidden">
  <input id="txt_tec_ins_cedula" type="hidden">
  <input id="txt_tec_ins_nombre" type="hidden">
  <input id="txt_tec_ins_cargo" type="hidden">
  <input id="txt_tec_ins_v" type="hidden"><br>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Agregar técnico a inspección" id='btnagregartecins'>
```

$('#btnagregartecins').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

```
    tec_ins_id_tecnicos_1 = $('#txt_tec_ins_id_tecnicos').val();
    tec_ins_tecnicos_1_v = $('#txt_tec_ins_v').val();
    tec_ins_tecnicos_1 = $('#txt_tec_ins').val();

    //alert('Tecnicoid:' + tec_ins_id_tecnicos_1);

    if(tec_ins_id_tecnicos_1 == '' || tec_ins_tecnicos_1_v != tec_ins_tecnicos_1){
        alert('Debe seleccionar el técnico.');
        return;
    }


        var datosTecIns = {
            tec_ins_id_tecnicos         : $('#txt_tec_ins_id_tecnicos').val()
        };

        //alert('Tecnicoid:' + tec_ins_id_tecnicos_1);

        $.post('php/agregartecins.php', datosTecIns, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            if (data == 0){
                alert('No se pudo procesar. Intente mas tarde.');
                return;
            }
            if (data == 2){
                alert('No se ha ingresado el técnico a la inspeccion.');
                return;
            }
            if (data == 3){
                alert('No se pudo procesar. Error al insertar.');
                return;
            }
            if (data > 10){
                alert('Se ha guardado correctamente el registro: ' + data);
                $.post('php/cuadrilla_actualiza.php', datosTecIns, function(data2, textStatus, xhr) {
                    $('#datoscuadrilla').html(data2);
                });

                 optionstec = '';
                $.post('php/consultarCedulas.php', datosTecIns, function(data3, textStatus, xhr) {

                    optionstec = data3;
                    //alert(optionstec);
                });
                //alert("Procesando...");
                setTimeout ('Actualiza_select_tec()', 2000);




                return;
            }
            alert('Error:' + data);


        });


});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplentemente colocas al final del ajax cuando te de succes asi:

```
$('#txt_tec_ins').val("");
```

al indicar `.val("")` estas limpiando el valor. Saludos